# Single-instanced struct with maybe preallocated databuffer

Tags: rust

So i'm trying to replicate a very fast C library which basically preallocates X amount of bytes to accomodate 99% of the use cases.

Data comes in, if size needed is less than X then it uses a stack pre-allocated buffer. If it doesnt the C library uses malloc.

I'm trying to do the same with rust but i think i'm using the wrong approach.

```
static mut TMP:[u64; 32] = [1u64; 32];

pub struct MaybePreallocated<'a> {
    pub x: &'a [u64]    
}

impl MaybePreallocated<'_> {
    pub fn new(howmany: usize) -> Self {
        if (howmany > 32) {
            MaybePreallocated {
                /// ????
            }
        } else {
            MaybePreallocated {
                x: &TMP
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Besides the "????" i really need to mutate the underlying data as part of the computation and i can, for now, be sure that only one instance of MaybePreallocated will exist.

The static mut is a bit scary tbh and would also love to have the dynamically allocated vec/slice to be freed when nobody owns any MaybePreallocated.

Is this possible in Rust?

If yes, how?

Comment: Sounds like you're basically trying to rewrite the [`smallvec`](https://crates.io/crates/smallvec) crate…